# css : In chrome ,why table width goes beyond its container width?

Tags: css, firefox

Please visit [holiday.ge](http://holiday.ge) and scroll down to the calendar. In firefox calendar behaves as expected, but in chrome calendar goes beyond its dedicated space. I could limit space of links themselves with max width. But logically it should work correctly as it is now.

Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it without the borders on the tds? I would also try it without the widths on the td too and go from there. You might need to set pixel widths.

Comment: problem has nothing to do with borders.

Comment: did you try takings the widths off? could also be the padding in the theaders - you could just align center rather than pad.